# Offline copy of Mac OS X Reference Library?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there an offline copy of **Mac OS X Reference Library** for download?

My connection is not always available so it would be useful to have a local copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the Mac OS X Reference Library in Xcode is downloaded locally start under Help->Developer documentation

Comment: It is not offline , it connects to apple and fetches the pages

Comment: There are a lot of elements that are fetched over the web e.g. Examples and PDF versions of the documentation, but all the standard references are resolved locally once the collection has been installed

Comment: Nothing that is so useful it could actually be used offline. Unplug your network, turn off wifi and try using that. It doesn't work.